# Is this sentence written correctly?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

> He went to prison a frightened entrepreneur. He left a hardened criminal.

It's not written by me. I read it somewhere, and I just wonder if it's grammatically correct.

Comment: Hi Jay, we don't generally do spotting errors and making corrections; is there anything in particular you're concerned about in terms of its correctness? What makes you think it might not be correct?

Comment: @SamBC I think it mean "When he went to prison, he was a frightened entrepreneur. When he left there, he was(became) a hardened criminal". Am I right? I don't know but for me, these two sentences seem just somewhat odd.

Comment: Okay, let's see if we can't parse it for you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sentence like the first, the description *a frightened entrepreneur* is an adverbial phrase describing the state of the subject. Actually, a sentence of this structure can have the adverbial describing the state of the object as well, but in this case it's obviously the subject. You might think of it as having a missing *as*:

> He went to prison **as** a frightened entrepreneur.

The second is a parallel structure, but omits the object of the verb because it is the same as the previous sentence - it is obvious *where* he left, so it does not need to be stated.

Overall, the whole thing might be rewritten as follows:

> When he went to prison he was a frightened entrepreneur. When he left, he was a hardened criminal.

It means that he became a hardened criminal while in prison. It is a very common turn of phrase, a very common structure used to indicate a change of state between two events, usually linked events.